# Ionic Drag down entire screen

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

when I touch the navbar and drag downward it moves entire screen.

[open this image to see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uHZk.jpg)

I'm using ionic 1.2.1

This happen only in iPhone devices. Anyone have same problem?

Comment: If you don't share any code, it is really hard to help.

Comment: i don't know which code could be usefull. I'm using only ionic's standard directive. <Ion-nav-bar> and <ion-tabs>. 

I can add that i'm using phonegap build to create .ipa

Comment: Because it is wrongly configured. There is an error in your setup.The default touch behavior is not correctly turned of.

Comment: Does the screen stay 'moved' to the bottom?  Meaning, does it pop back into place after you drag down?

Comment: this is solution! http://www.chrishjorth.com/blog/phonegap-remove-view-scrolling-on-ios/